# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/analysis/OverrideFunctionRegistry

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hivecontext

I have tried with below code in spark and scala, attaching code and pom.xml

```
package com.Spark.ConnectToHadoop

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
//import groovy.sql.Sql.CreateStatementCommand

//import org.apache.spark.SparkConf


object CountWords  {

  def main(args:Array[String]){

    val objConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Spark Connection").setMaster("spark://IP:7077")
    var sc = new SparkContext(objConf)
val objHiveContext = new HiveContext(sc)
objHiveContext.sql("USE test")


var test= objHiveContext.sql("show tables")
    var i  = 0

    var testing = test.collect()
      for(i<-0 until testing.length){

      println(testing(i))
    }
  }
}
```

I have added spark-core_2.10,spark-catalyst_2.10,spark-sql_2.10,spark-hive_2.10 dependencies Do I need to add any more dependencies???

Edit:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.Sudhir.Maven1</groupId>
    <artifactId>SparkDemo</artifactId>
    <version>IntervalMeterData1</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>SparkDemo</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <spark.version>1.5.2</spark.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2</version>
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-catalyst_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-hive_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
            <artifactId>hive-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>     
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: 1. How are you running your spark - local/remote? 2. If not running local, do you have a spark version built with hive support?

Comment: remote, I didn't gety you what does built with hive support mean,. I previously connected when it was 1.4.1

Comment: Are you sure you are running your code an installation of spark 1.5 with hive support? The OverrideFunctionRegistry was replaced with HiveFunctionRegistry for spark 1.5 in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-8883

Comment: yes spark installation 1.5.2 with hive support too(yarn cluster mode)..
hive version 1.2.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you forgot to bump the spark-hive:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-hive_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Consider introducing maven variable, like spark.version.

```
   <properties>
        <spark.version>1.5.2</spark.version>
    </properties>
```

And modifying all your spark dependencies in this manner:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-hive_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Bumping up versions of spark won't be as painful.

Just adding the property `spark.version` in your `<properties>` is not enough, you have to call it with `${spark.version}` in dependencies.

Comment: Thanks alot, that issue is resolved and getting below exception Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: The root scratch dir: /tmp/hive on HDFS should be writable. Current permissions are: rw-rw-rw-,
evrn though I have given 777 permissions